# Multiplying two adjacency matrices element-wise, one larger than the other

Tags: r, matrix

I'm working with two, square adjacency matrices. One is smaller than the other but the smaller one is a subset of the larger.

I'm not sure if this is a job for crossprod, matrix multiplication, or what. Do I need to just make a subset of the larger matrix and then multiply later?

Is there an easier way to just say "hey see these column/row names in the small table, multiply their corresponding column/names in the large table?"

```
m1<-matrix(1,5,5)
colnames(m1)<-LETTERS[1:5]
rownames(m1)<-LETTERS[1:5]
m1
#   A B C D E
# A 1 1 1 1 1
# B 1 1 1 1 1
# C 1 1 1 1 1
# D 1 1 1 1 1
# E 1 1 1 1 1

m2<-matrix(1:9,3,3)
colnames(m2)<-c("D","A","C")
rownames(m2)<-c("D","A","C")
m2
#   D A C
# D 1 4 7
# A 4 5 8
# C 7 8 9

hoping to get something that looks like
if I multiply m1 * m2:
#   A B C D E
# A 5 1 8 4 1  -> reflects multiplication from matching adjacency in smaller table
# B 1 1 1 1 1  -> stays the same
# C 8 1 9 7 1  -> reflects multiplication from matching adjacency in smaller table
# D 4 1 7 1 1 -> reflects multiplication from matching adjacency in smaller table
# E 1 1 1 1 1  -> stays the same
```

Comment: The instruction that creates `m2` does not create the posted matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to subset the larger matrix using the row and column names of the smaller matrix. Something like the following.

```
mult <- function(large, small){
    rn <- rownames(small)
    cn <- colnames(small)
    large[rn, cn] <- large[rn, cn]*small
    large
}

mult(m1, m2)
#  A B C D E
#A 5 1 8 2 1
#B 1 1 1 1 1
#C 6 1 9 3 1
#D 4 1 7 1 1
#E 1 1 1 1 1
```

If you want more complicated multiplications, such as `(large + 3)^2 * log(small+1)`, as long as the dimensions and row/column names remain compatible just pass those matrices to `mult`.

```
mult((m1 + 3)^2, log(m2 + 1))
#         A  B        C        D  E
#A 28.66815 16 35.15559 17.57780 16
#B 16.00000 16 16.00000 16.00000 16
#C 31.13456 16 36.84136 22.18071 16
#D 25.75101 16 33.27106 11.09035 16
#E 16.00000 16 16.00000 16.00000 16
```

If these transformations of `large` and `small` are to be done several times, define functions:

```
f <- function(m) (m + 3)^2
g <- function(m) log(m + 1)

mult(f(m1), g(m2))
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: Thank you so much Rui! That seemed to work. Any ideas on how to make that function work if it's a slightly more complicated multiplication?

For example:

(large + 3)^2 * log(small+1)